# Remove Fabric in Production release

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I just start discovering Fabric.
I understand stand Crashlytics is for Beta-testing your apps.

But what I like to know is, do people keep Crashlytics (or other Fabric options) in their production versions of apps?

Comment: Thats one of the main points of Crashlytics, to keep it in your production apps and see crashes that are occurring in production so you can fix them.

Comment: Agreed. Removing Crashlytics in production defeats most of its value. You want it most from those least likely to report issues.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with sbarrow and Rob (from comments section) But if you really want to remove it from production.

Inside your AppDelegate.swift in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` just add a code like this

```
if debug {
     Fabric.with([Crashlitics.self])
}
```

What this would do is, it would only run Crashlytics code if you're debugging